# QT resources doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I'm writing a program that is supposed to work on the other computer, so I need to have my `.txt` files with it.

I have created a **QT resource file** and added one `.txt` file, then I used it in three windows. It worked perfectly fine until I added another `.txt` file to resource that is being used in only one window.

So I have `users.txt` file from which I am logging to program and managing users accounts and I have `cars.txt` which is a database for cars.

```
QFile text(":konta/users.txt");
text.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream wczytaj(&text);
```

This part works but in the next window

```
QFile text(":konta/users.txt");
    text.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream wczytaj(&text);
```

This part doesn't work, I have function which checks if file is open and if it exists, and they returns that it exists but is not open.

and now the newest window:

```
QFile baza(":/auta/cars.txt");
     baza.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream zapisz(&baza);
    if(!baza.exists()){QMessageBox::warning(this,"Uwaga","Baza nie została odnaleziona");}
    else if(!baza.isOpen()){QMessageBox::warning(this,"Uwaga","Baza nie została otworzona");}
```

Same issue here, the file exists but is not opened. It's weird that it works in one window. Before I added the second `.txt` file, all the cases worked (except the third part of the code which didn't exist at that time). I didn't change anything in those files or functions.

I should also add that if I  give them full path to the file `C/folder/folder/file.txt`, it works with no problems, but I need it to work on other computers as well, so it's not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that problem may be with currents path. When you start your application from Qt Designer current path is ../ (parent of the current directory). When your start your application directly default path is ./ (current directory where your .exe is). You may use this code to get universal path to default directory:

```
QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath() % "/";
```

By the way you may use QFileDialog class to let you user choose files manually. And it is better to use SqLite for storing you users, cars etc. than text files. Qt provides in-built support for SqLite - it it fast and easy to use.